# Chrome Notifications No Longer Display (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, unity, google-chrome, notification

I recently reinstalled 14.04, and Chrome notifications worked great for about 2 days, after which there were no gmail notifications or Now cards and now there isn't even the bell icon.

The Chrome and Hangouts icons are still there and work as intended, and I've tried uninstalling Chrome, wiping configurations, and then reinstalling but still nothing. I don't remember installing something else around the time it stopped working, but I guess anything is possible. I did at some point set up Thunderbird (now uninstalled), which I think uses the same bell icon, but I can't remember if that coincided with Chrome's notifications not working anymore.

Is there a known workaround? It's working in Windows, and while not essential I find it breaks my writing flow a lot less to click on the indicator instead of pulling out my phone to check my notifications.

Any help is super appreciated!